# HTML5 canvas stroke with consistent alpha values

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, alpha, overlapping

I am developing a image masking tool that helps the user mark a certain regions on an underlying image. I'd like the mask to have a consistent alpha-value. The masking tool is to be implemented in HTML5 canvas.

The issue I'm facing is that when I create multiple over-lapping strokes, their alpha values stack, making it less-transparent in the overlaps. Whereas I'd like a consistent alpha value regardless of overlapping strokes, as the user might need multiple strokes to fully mask a region.

```
Here is the attached fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/o5x70fbd/
```

Let me know if this is a known solution

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reset transparency when drawing overlapping content on HTML canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33723384/how-to-reset-transparency-when-drawing-overlapping-content-on-html-canvas)

Comment: And since you seem to be using a single stroke color, that would make a good candidate too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34363838/layering-rectangles-on-a-canvas-causes-opacity-to-increase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is the solution you are looking for. My idea is to use 2 canvases. In the first canvas the color of the stroke is opaque. This canvas is hidden. I'm using `display:none`but you can let it unattached to the DOM.

Then you copy the first canvas as an image in a second one with `ctx2.globalAlpha = .5;`. this will give you a a consistent alpha value.

The changes I've made to your code: I'm putting the points in arrays and I'm drawing using the points:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var canvas2 = document.getElementById("_2");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var ctx2 = _2.getContext("2d");
var drawing = false;
let points = [];

var painting = document.getElementById("paint");
var paint_style = getComputedStyle(painting);
canvas.width = canvas2.width = parseInt(paint_style.getPropertyValue("width"));
canvas.height = canvas2.height = parseInt(
  paint_style.getPropertyValue("height")
);

var mouse = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0
};

let count = -1;
ctx.lineWidth = 30;
ctx.lineJoin = "round";
ctx.lineCap = "round";

_2.addEventListener(
  "mousemove",
  function(e) {
    if (drawing) {
      mouse.x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
      mouse.y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
      points[count].push({ x: mouse.x, y: mouse.y });
      onPaint();
    }
  },
  false
);

_2.addEventListener(
  "mousedown",
  function(e) {
    drawing = true;
    count++;
    mouse.x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    mouse.y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
    let ry = [];
    ry.push({ x: mouse.x, y: mouse.y });
    points.push(ry);
  },
  false
);

_2.addEventListener(
  "mouseup",
  function() {
    drawing = false;
    onPaint();
  },
  false
);

function onPaint() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  points.forEach(ry => {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(ry[0].x, ry[0].y);
    ry.forEach(p => {
      ctx.lineTo(p.x, p.y);
    });
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#00CC99";
    ctx.stroke();
  });

  ctx2.clearRect(0, 0, canvas2.width, canvas2.height);
  ctx2.globalAlpha = 0.5;
  ctx2.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0);
}
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#paint {
    width: 98%;
    height: 550px;
    border: 5px solid red;
}

#myCanvas{display:none;}

#_2{background:url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/castell.jpg)}
```

```html
<div id="paint">
    <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
    <canvas id="_2"></canvas>
</div>
```